# Using two summarise function in r

Tags: r

```
 library(lubridate)
 library(tidyverse)
 step_count_raw <- read_csv("data/step-count/step-count.csv",
 locale = locale(tz = "Australia/Melbourne"))
 location <- read_csv("data/step-count/location.csv")
 step_count <- step_count_raw %>% 
 rename_with(~ c("date_time", "date", "count")) %>% 
 left_join(location) %>% 
 mutate(location = replace_na(location, "Melbourne"))
 step_count

 #> # A tibble: 5,448 x 4
 #>    date_time           date       count location 
 #>    <dttm>              <date>     <dbl> <chr>    
 #>  1 2019-01-01 09:00:00 2019-01-01   764 Melbourne
 #>  2 2019-01-01 10:00:00 2019-01-01   913 Melbourne
 #>  3 2019-01-02 00:00:00 2019-01-02     9 Melbourne
 #>  4 2019-01-02 10:00:00 2019-01-02  2910 Melbourne
 #>  5 2019-01-02 11:00:00 2019-01-02  1390 Melbourne
 #>  6 2019-01-02 12:00:00 2019-01-02  1020 Melbourne
 #>  7 2019-01-02 13:00:00 2019-01-02   472 Melbourne
 #>  8 2019-01-02 15:00:00 2019-01-02  1220 Melbourne
 #>  9 2019-01-02 16:00:00 2019-01-02  1670 Melbourne
 #> 10 2019-01-02 17:00:00 2019-01-02  1390 Melbourne
 #> # … with 5,438 more rows
```

I want to calculate average daily step counts for every location, from step_count. Then end up with a tibble called city_avg_steps.

expected output

```
 #> # A tibble: 4 x 2
 #>   location      avg_count
 #>   <chr>             <dbl>
 #> 1 Austin            7738.
 #> 2 Denver           12738.
 #> 3 Melbourne         7912.
 #> 4 San Francisco    13990.
```

My code and output

```
  city_avg_steps <- step_count%>%group_by(location)%>%summarise(avg_count=mean(count))
  city_avg_steps
  
  # A tibble: 4 x 2
  location      avg_count
  <chr>             <dbl>
  1 Austin             721.
  2 Denver             650.
  3 Melbourne          530.
  4 San Francisco      654.
```

I have a clue is to calculate daily number first then cumulate the result using two summarise fuction，but not sure how to add.

Comment: Do `group_by(location, date) %>% summarize(steps = sum(count))`. That will get you total steps per day per location. With modern dplyr it'll also automatically strip one level of grouping. So then you can just do `summarize(avg_count = mean(steps))`.

Comment: It gives tibble: 1 x 1.

Comment: So then check the grouping and if need be regroup manually

Comment: I regrouped it,it gives 4 same number.

Comment: You're gonna need to show your code.

Comment: city_avg_steps <-step_count%>%group_by(location)%>%summarise(steps=sum(count))%>%summarize(location,avg_count = mean(steps))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231543/discussion-between-dash2-and-kee).

Answer (score 1):

As @dash2 explains in the comments, from what we understand from your desired output, it requires a two stage aggregation, one to aggregate the number of steps per day (adding them together, using `sum`), the other is aggregating the different days into location level averages, using `mean`.

```
step_count %>% 
  group_by(date, location) %>% 
  summarise(sum_steps = sum(count, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(avg_steps = mean(sum_steps, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: You should explain your solution, code only answers may get downvoted or flagged for revision.